# CS0266 cannot convert type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an error:

> CS0266 C# Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedIQueryable'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is my controller:

```
public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
    ViewBag.NameSurnameSortParm = sortOrder == "NameSurname" ? "NameSurname_desc" : "NameSurname";
    ViewBag.ReasonSortParm = sortOrder == "Reason" ? "Reason_desc" : "Reason";
    ViewBag.AccessSortParm = sortOrder == "Access" ? "Access_desc" : "Access";
    ViewBag.UserOrAdminSortParm = sortOrder == "UserOrAdmin" ? "UserOrAdmin_desc" : "UserOrAdmin";

    ViewBag.DepartmentSortParm = sortOrder == "Department" ? "Department_desc" : "Department";
    ViewBag.UNCPathSortParm = sortOrder == "UNCPath" ? "UNCPath_desc" : "UNCPath";

    if (searchString != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }

    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

    var request = from c in _context.RaidRequest
                    orderby c.Id
                    select c;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        request = request.Where(s => s.NameSurname.Contains(searchString));
    }

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "NameSurname_desc":
            request = request.OrderByDescending(c => c.NameSurname);
            break;
        case "Reason":
            request = request.OrderBy(c => c.Reason);
            break;
        case "Reason_desc":
            request = request.OrderByDescending(c => c.Reason);
            break;
        case "Access":
            request = request.OrderBy(c => c.Access);
            break;
        case "Access_desc":
            request = request.OrderByDescending(c => c.Access);
            break;
        case "UserOrAdmin":
            request = request.OrderBy(c => c.UserOrAdmin);
            break;
        case "UserOrAdmin_desc":
            request = request.OrderByDescending(c => c.UserOrAdmin);
            break;
        case "Department":
            request = request.OrderBy(c => c.Department);
            break;
        case "Department_desc":
            request = request.OrderByDescending(c => c.Department);
            break;
        case "UNCPath":
            request = request.OrderBy(c => c.UNCPath);
            break;
        case "UNCPath_desc":
            request = request.OrderByDescending(c => c.UNCPath);
            break;
    }

    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return View(request.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

This part of its broken :

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    request = request.Where(s => s.NameSurname.Contains(searchString));
}
```

Can you please explain what to do ?
I followed the tutorial word by word. It worked until I added pagination.
could it be something with my View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your queries contain an orderby, therefore returning an `IOrderedQueryable`, except the query where you use the searchstring. This query returns an `IQueryable`.

Since `IOrderedQueryable` is inheriting from `IQueryable` you can assign an `IOrderedQueryable` to an `IQueryable`, but not the other way around.

Remove the orderby from the first query, and it will become an `IQueryable`, add a `default:` to the switch statement to do the default sorting. This will also prevent you sorting the resulting query twice.

```
    var request = from c in _context.RaidRequest
                      select c;

    // Your code
    switch (sortOrder)
        {
            // other cases
            case "UNCPath_desc":
                request = request.OrderByDescending(c => c.UNCPath);
                break;
            default: 
                request = request.OrderBy(c => c.Id);
                break;
        }
```

Comment: That didnt help my case. still The same error. i just got 1 new message next to the errors: IDE0066: use 'switch' expression

Comment: Did you remove the orderby from the first query?

Comment: No I didnt, my bad :D

Comment: Now that you are familliar with my controller, could you help me with my View also ? it has error CS0012: The type'MvcHtmlString' is defined in an assembly that is not refferenced.You must add a refference to assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=blablabla'

Comment: Create a new question.

Comment: Fair enough. Ill go and do that